# python convert ascii str to utf8 str

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

I have this string:

```
emission = "/home/guillaume/Vid\xc3\xa9os/pluzz/info_midi_102115995.mkv\n"
```

I would like to convert it to have:

```
emission = "/home/guillaume/Vidéos/pluzz/info_midi_102115995.mkv"
```

Here is my code: (the text come from a pseudo-term in my gtk window, using python-vte)

```
text = repr(self.v.get_text(lambda *a: True).rstrip())
if "Output #0" in text:
    line = text.split("matroska,",1)[1]    
    splitted = line.split() # to split the line   
    emission = splitted[1]  # to get the str
    emission = emission.replace("'", "")
    emission = emission.replace(":", "")        
    print "1", emission
    print type(emission)    
    emission = emission.decode("utf-8")
    print "2", emission
```

Result:

```
1 /home/guillaume/Vid\xc3\xa9os/pluzz/info_midi_102115995.mkv\n
<type 'str'>    
2 /home/guillaume/Vid\xc3\xa9os/pluzz/info_midi_102115995.mkv\n
```

Thanks

**Solution:** I had to change

```
text = repr(self.v.get_text(lambda *a: True).rstrip())
```

by:

```
text = str(self.v.get_text(lambda *a: True).rstrip())
```

Thanks to user 2357112!

Comment: What does "no results" mean? What actually happened when you tried that? Also, what Python version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm using python 2.7, and "no results" means that file is not converted.

Comment: What does "not converted" mean? Can you provide a transcript of an actual interpreter session where you attempt to convert your string to Unicode, so we don't have to guess what you're trying to say?

Comment: Your string doesn't contain UTF-8-encoded Unicode characters. The `\xc3\xa9` stuff isn't escape sequences; it's a literal backslash, x, c, 3, etc. in your string. Figure out why this is the case, and you'll solve your problem.

Comment: The text come from a vte terminal, a pseudo-term in my gtk window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54329/discussion-between-user2357112-and-guillaume).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> encoded = "/home/guillaume/Vid\xc3\xa9os/pluzz/info_midi_102115995.mkv\n"
>>> decoded = encoded.decode('utf-8')
>>> decoded
u'/home/guillaume/Vid\xe9os/pluzz/info_midi_102115995.mkv\n'
>>> print decoded
/home/guillaume/Vidéos/pluzz/info_midi_102115995.mkv
```

Assuming `file` is really a bytestring that really looks like what you've shown us, `file.decode("utf-8")` should have worked just fine (except for that newline at the end, which you'll have to `strip` off separately). The `\xe9` in the `repr` output appears because it's less ambiguous to print escape codes than to print arbitrary Unicode weirdness like zero-width spaces or that thing that makes text go backward; the decoded string contains the characters you want.

---

**Update**: With the posted code and output, we can see that the `repr` call is converting the input from encoded Unicode to textual UTF-8 escape sequences, with actual backslashes and hexadecimal instead of UTF-8 bytes. Changing the `repr` call to `str` fixed the problem. It's likely that removing `repr` entirely would do the same.

Comment: It's working in the terminal but not in my script! :/